# Infinite sequence of Natural numbers with Java8 generator

Tags: java, iterator, generator, java-8

I defined `natural` for Infinite sequence (`Stream`) of Natural numbers with Java8 `iterator`.

```
IntStream natural = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1);

natural
 .limit(10)
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now, I want to define it with Java8 `generator`.

static  Stream generate(Supplier s)

What would be the simplest way? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by generator? Do you mean `Supplier`?

Comment: Never worked with java 8,but is this what you're looking for http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793374/Generators-with-Java?

Comment: I believe using `Stream.generate(Supplier)` will be more complicated than what you have right now.

Comment: Joffrey, probably `static Stream generate(Supplier s)` , and Vinc, yes I've read the article, but unclear to me somehow. thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Note: @assylias managed to do it with a lambda using `AtomicInteger`.* He should probably have the accepted answer.

---

I'm not sure you can do that with a lambda (because it is stateful), but with a plain `Supplier` this would work:

```
IntSupplier generator = new IntSupplier() {
    int current = 0;

    public int getAsInt() {
        return current++;
    }
};

IntStream natural = IntStream.generate(generator);
```

However, **I highly prefer your current solution**, because this is the purpose of `iterate(int seed, IntUnaryOperator f)` IMHO:

```
IntStream natural = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1);
```

Comment: It's not infinite, though, is it? ;) -- for most purposes, this would be: ```IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? 0 : i + 1)``` -- I mean, if you just want to keep track of some process and are interested in a window. Otherwise, BigInteger maybe?

Comment: @Deroude Good point. Although I guess on a finite computer nothing is really infinite, `BigInteger` will be limited by the available memory at some point. I don't think it really matters in the context of the OP.

Answer (score 26):

With a generator you need to keep track of your current index. One way would be:

```
IntStream natural = IntStream.generate(new AtomicInteger()::getAndIncrement);
```

Note: I use AtomicInteger as a mutable integer rather than for its thread safety: if you parallelise the stream the order will not be as expected.

Comment: That's a concise way of doing this without having to create a class, I have to admit. +1. This answer should probably be the accepted one rather than mine.

Answer (score 24):

This is built into `IntStream`:

```
IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

This returns all values up to (but not including) `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.