# Implement counting variable with lambda expression java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a question about lambda expressions. I have a class Pair which should hold a String and an int.

Pair gets the String out of a file. 
and the int is representiv for the line number. 
So far I have this:

```
 Stream<String> lineNumbers = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
    List<Integer> posStream = Stream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1).limit(lineNumbers.count()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    lineNumbers.close();
    Stream<String> line = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
    List<Pair> pairs = line.map((f) -> new Pair<>(f,1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    pairs.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.toString()));
    line.close();
```

How can I now input the file numbers to the pairs? 
Is there a lambda expression which can perform this? Or do I need something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The counter technique suggested by [Saloparenator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29850758/1441122) could be implemented as follows, using an `AtomicInteger` as the mutable counter object and assuming the obvious `Pair` class:

```
List<Pair> getPairs1() throws IOException {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILENAME))) {
        return lines.parallel()
                    .map(line -> new Pair(line, counter.incrementAndGet()))
                    .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the stream is run in parallel, the counter won't be incremented in the same order as the lines are read! This will occur if your file has several thousand lines. The `Files.lines` stream source will batch up bunches of lines and dispatch them to several threads, which will then number their batches in parallel, interleaving their calls to `incrementAndGet()`. Thus, the lines won't be numbered sequentially. It will work if you can guarantee that your stream will never run in parallel, but it's often a bad idea to write streams that are likely to return different results sequentially vs. in parallel.

Here's another approach. Since you're reading all the lines into memory no matter what, just read them all into a list. Then use a stream to number them:

```
static List<Pair> getPairs2() throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(FILENAME));
    return IntStream.range(0, lines.size())
                    .parallel()
                    .mapToObj(i -> new Pair(lines.get(i), i+1))
                    .collect(toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another functional way would be to ZIP your list of stream with a integer generator

(I can see java8 dont have it yet but it is essentially merging every cell of two list in a list of pair, so it is easy to implement)

You can see example of generator in java8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277330/infinite-sequence-of-natural-numbers-with-java8-generator)

Answer (score -1):

```
int cnt = 1;
List<Pair> pairs = line.map((f) -> new Pair<>(f,cnt++))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have not tried it yet but may work.

Comment: That dont work, because a lambda expression need a final to perform it so i cant increase a value inside a lambda expression

Comment: Then i think you cant perform what he want using lambda.
Anyway lambda should not be used in mutable way.

Comment: It's a small method in my homework which is about lambda expressions and streams xD

Comment: you can build an counter object that increase value every get,
declare it final and use it in your lambda.

By definition lambda are idempotent, mean if you call it several time with the same param, it will return de same result every time. This is why I say  increasing a value inside lambda is anti-functional.

Comment: use final atomicInteger; .map(arr ->new Integer(i.getAndIncrement()))....